# Editing the post time displayed for comments in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, comments

I need to display the post time of comments for a particular content type. I want these post times of comments to be in the "time ago" format.

Example: 1 minute ago

How can I do this in Drupal 7?

Comment: In the future, tag your questions with the "7" tag instead of writing "Drupal 7."  This will make searching for them much easier.

Comment: @PatrickKenny There's been some discussion about the 6/7 version tags on [meta].  Check out [Version tags considered harmful](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229/version-tags-considered-harmful) and [Version tags considered harmful](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok).  I'm not really sure I agree with the premise, but apparently using version tags is not cool for every question =\

Answer (score 1):

There is a native function in Drupal to format date intervals, it is called [format_interval](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_interval/7).

Usage example:

```
 // Date since forum post was created
 format_interval(REQUEST_TIME - $variables['topic']->created)
```

Hope this helps, happy coding!

PS: See the answer I gave on your stackexchange post for the longer custom version you can also use.

Comment: The PS doesn't help other users of this site without linking to the original stack Exchange question - maybe you  could post the link to that question/answer as part of your answer?